# php extensions error with ssh2

Tags: php, ssh

I got an error as

> [16-Dec-2015 11:38:02] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/spider/lamp/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ssh2.so' - libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

What is wrong?

The configuration is as follows...
[image]

I have the .so files as below:
[image]

Comment: do you actually have a space in `ss h2.so`?

Comment: Does the extension exist in your extension directory?

Comment: have you installed ss2? if not then try `apt-get install libssh2-1-dev libssh2-php` and then restart server

Comment: @Andrey no, does it need one space?

Comment: I have installed the ssh2.

Comment: The error message you provided contains a space, while it shouldn't be there.

Comment: My bad, in the log, there is no space between.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to load dynamic library '/home/spider/lamp/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ssh2.so' - libssh2.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Shared libraries may contain dependencies on other shared libraries, just like executable programs can. In this case, `ssh2.so` contains a dependency on another shared library named `libssh2.so.1`, and the linker can't find the latter file.